How does PySpark caching work if I unpersist a parent dataframe?
Consider I have
df1 = ...  #  some complicated query 
df1 = df1.cache()

df2 = f(df1)  # some complicated query which depends on df1 and re-uses it multiple times
df1.unpersist()
# At this point df1 and df2 are both "lazy" plans.

df2.count()  # actually need to evaluate  df2

When running the last line, is df1 going to be cached or not during the computation?
In other scenario:
df1 = ...  #  some complicated query 
df1 = df1.cache()

df2 = f(df1)  # some complicated query which depends on df1 and re-uses it multiple times
df2 = df2.cache()
# At this point df1 and df2 are both "lazy" plans.

df2.count()  # actually need to evaluate  df2
df1.unpersist()

After running the last line here, is df2 going to be fully cached and never needs to be recomputed, so that df1 also never needs to be recomputed when using df2?
